# Is there a better way to check if the values of an AJAX request are valid?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm in the process of building an AJAX backend for a Django application, and I don't know if I'm building it right. Currently to accept integer values, I need to typecast them into integers using int(), which raises exceptions and ends up in a 500 all the time if I don't apply much boilerplate. This causes my code to look slightly messier than I would like, and I don't know if I'm doing it correctly. This is an example AJAX view from the app:

```
@ajax_required
def poll(request):
    try:
        last_id = int(request.POST.get('last_id'))
        feed_type = request.POST['feed_type']
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()

    if feed_type == 'following' and request.user.is_authenticated():
        posts = Post.get_posts(user=request.user, after_id=last_id)
        return JsonResponse({
            'html': render_to_string('posts/raw_posts.html', {'posts': posts}),
            'count': posts.count()
        })

    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

As you see, I have to do a lot of boilerplate and silence some exceptions of the language itself, which concerns me, coming from a PHP background. Is there a better way to do this or am I doing things correctly?

Comment: Catch a KeyError and forget the if, using  `request.POST["last_id"]`, what raises a `TypeError`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The problem with such approach is when typecasting to int it raises a TypeError.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YsTDFjCL when casting it should raise a ValueError for bad input

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Hm, that's nice. Will change. EDIT: Done

Comment: You last  `return HttpResponseBadRequest()` is also unreachable, you can remove it altogether as I imagine ir should only be returned  for bad input

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xJCE0fPD The else is also redundant, you cannot return twice

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you so much for the observations, will edit now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not opposed to using a framework [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will handle serialization and deserialization for you, it is super easy to define custom validation beyond simple type checking, and it's gorgeous. Tom Christie has even [wrapped it up](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-marshmallow) for use with Django.

Edit:
If you choose to use it your code would look more like this:

```
from rest_marshmallow import Schema, fields

class FeedSchema(Schema):
    last_id = fields.Integer()
    feed_type = fields.String()

@ajax_required
def poll(request):
    try:
        # Validate request
        serializer = FeedSchema(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = serializer.validated_data
        # Return posts
        if data['feed_type'] == 'following' and request.user.is_authenticated():
            posts = Post.get_posts(user=request.user, after_id=data['last_id'])
            return JsonResponse({
                'html': render_to_string('posts/raw_posts.html', {'posts': posts}),
                'count': posts.count()
            })
        # The user isn't authenticated or they requested a feed type they don't have access to.
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    except ValidationError as err:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(err.messages)
```

Comment: Looks a lot like Django forms, I'm digging it. Will try it for sure. Thanks!